# NullPointerException in changing javaFX scene

Tags: javafx, fxml, scene, scenebuilder

I have two scenes in my javaFx project .. the first one `Language.fxml` has a button which on click changes the scene to `allDevices.fxml` .. but it throws `NullPointerException` saying "Location is required" although both of the fxml files are in the same path !!

that's my `LanguageController.java`

```
package astrolabe;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Ahmed Fawzy
 */
public class LanguageController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button arabic ;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        arabic.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try{
                    Node node=(Node) event.getSource();
                    Stage stage=(Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
                    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("allDevices.fxml"));/* Exception */
                    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                    stage.setScene(scene);
                    stage.show();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: Log the URL you are getting with `System.out.println(getClass().getResource("allDevices.fxml").toExternalForm());` to see if it's giving you what you expect.

Comment: @James_D when adding`System.out.println(getClass().getResource("allDevices.fxml").toExternalForm());‌​` it gave me a syntax error !!

Comment: Type it in: seems like copy and paste is somehow including some invisible characters that are confusing the parser.

Comment: @James_D `file:/D:/museum/Astrolabe/build/classes/astrolabe/allDevices.fxml` as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved by adding the package name before the fxml file name !